# I want to retrieve the text inside a html tag on a specific line

Tags: python, urllib

I am using html.parser and urllib.request. I am not going to use any non-native modules, but I am open to using other native ones if they are necessary.
Currently (a portion of) my code looks like this:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.getpos()[0] == 167:
            print(self.data)
```

The issue I am having is that HTMLParser.getpos always returns a tuple of (1, x), where x is a number that increases each time, but seemingly randomly), like this:

```
(1, 21)
(1, 41)
(1, 51)
(1, 77)
(1, 134)
(1, 206)
(1, 406)
(1, 509)
(1, 553)
(1, 627)
(1, 680)
(1, 784)
(1, 1143)
(1, 1368)
```

I feel like the whole html.parser module is written in a very stupid way and could have been thought out much better. Obviously it works, but it's counter-intuitive.

 
Full code:

```
from urllib.request import *
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
      print(self.getpos())
      if self.getpos()[0] == 167:
        print(data)
parser = MyHTMLParser()
html = urlopen("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/aha/takeonme.html").read()
parser.feed(str(html))
```

Comment: What is it you want your code to do that it isn't doing right? Are you trying to print the 167th line of HTML? Could you tell us what the HTML you're parsing looks like? (if it says it's only on line 1 I'd guess it's a one-line file). Also I don't really see what calling a Python library that you insist on using stupid adds to the question.

Comment: The HTML is a page like [this](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/aha/takeonme.html). I'm trying to take the lyric (string) data from inside a div tag that always is on line 167 and assign it to a string variable. I'm saying it's stupid because it is - it adds to the question because it is a warning to other people to maybe use a more intuitive module. I'm not _insisting_ on using it, I have to use it because my school computers only have native modules, so I'm making sure I don't get 5 people telling me to use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Could you post the full code sample that's producing that output? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to parse data from a div - you should track when you enter the div and exit the div, and accumulate data in between these points. This is easy to do with the library, and lies a lot closer to the actual parsing, although I'm not going to get into a debate about what's stupid and what isn't.

Your problem with line numbers is because you're using `str` to read a `bytes` object. In the interpreter, you can see why this is a problem:

```
>>> str(b"ab\nc")
"b'ab\\nc'"
```

It doesn't actually convert it to a kind of equivalent string, but to a string representation. This means newlines in the bytes object are represented literally as `\n`, so you're not getting any line numbers. To decode a bytes object, you should use `.decode`. The following code should work:

```
import sys

from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen

class LyricParser(HTMLParser):
    def get_lyrics(self, html):
        self.read_lyrics = False
        self.lyrics = []
        self.feed(html)
        return "".join(self.lyrics)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "div" and self.getpos()[0] == 167:
            self.read_lyrics = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.read_lyrics:
            self.lyrics.append(data)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "div":
            self.read_lyrics = False

parser = LyricParser()
page = urlopen("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/aha/takeonme.html")
lyrics = parser.get_lyrics(page.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(lyrics)
```

For me this correctly outputs something like:

```
Talking away
I don't know what I'm to say
I'll say it anyway
Today's another day to find you
...
```

Having looked at the page I must conclude you're right - it's bizzarely structured, and the only way to indentify the lyrics div is by line number, or maybe number of previous divs - if the line number ever fails, you could try keeping a count of divs met in `handle_starttag`.

Comment: Thank you! Well explained and improved my code greatly!